# Who should control the presenting of a new UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Ok, I have a somewhat trivial question that bugs me. When I present a new `UIView`, should that view control how its displayed and removed?

It feels like that would be a good idea, the view becomes self contained. Similar to `UIAlertView`:

```
[alertView show];
```

But on the other hand, it feels like something else should control it and should not be left to itself.

```
[self.view addSubview:newView];
[UIView animateWithDuration...];
```

Or is this 6 one way, half a dozen the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIAlertView is a special case—it gets added to its own window, not any existing part of your view hierarchy. If you’re not doing anything special like that, your second example is the correct approach.

That said, if this view is a custom class that you’re going to use in multiple places and want to behave consistently, it should control its own presentation. For instance, UIActionSheet’s `-showInView:` method takes care of adding itself as a subview, positioning itself, animating in, and so on.